# Postgres server not starting after unexpected Yosemite shutdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, permissions, server, rails-postgresql

I'm trying to start a rails server but I'm getting this error...

```
/Users/kweihe/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

if I check my postgres server processes I get this ...

```
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ ps auxw | grep postgres
kweihe          11687   0.0  0.0  2432772    636 s000  S+   10:56AM   0:00.00 grep postgres
```

so I've tried the following ...

```
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$  rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres 
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "kweihe".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... initdb: could not change permissions of directory "/usr/local/var/postgres": Operation not permitted
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ chmod 0700 /usr/local/var/postgres
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/var/postgres: Operation not permitted
```

so then I checked permissions ...

```
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ cd /usr/local/var/
kweihe-mac:var kweihe$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr--r--  2 root  admin  68 Jul 22 10:59 postgres
kweihe-mac:var kweihe$
```

and tried to enable all permissions ...

```
kweihe-mac:var kweihe$ chmod 777 postgres
chmod: Unable to change file mode on postgres: Operation not permitted
```

So then I almost got there with this ...

```
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "kweihe".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

creating directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in /usr/local/var/postgres/base/1 ... ok
initializing pg_authid ... ok
initializing dependencies ... ok
creating system views ... ok
loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
creating collations ... ok
creating conversions ... ok
creating dictionaries ... ok
setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
creating information schema ... FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 11413) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"
could not remove file or directory "/usr/local/var/postgres": Directory not empty
initdb: failed to remove data directory
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the problem is a running `launchctl` process which depends on `/usr/local/var/postgres`. In my case, thesolution was to stop it with

`launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

Finish off with (removing the directory in case it was partially created before)

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

here's my workflow notes

kept trying to run but kept failing

```
 initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres/
```

postgres kept generating a new directory in /usr/local/var/ that had incorrect permissions

Solution:

```
brew uninstall postgres
```

restart computer

directory /usr/local/var/postgres was somehow generated again (with incorrect permissions)

checked postgres installation to make sure it wasn’t installed

removed that directory

restarted computer again

```
brew install postgres
```

correct postgres directory generated

postmaster.pid file not there

tried running `initdb` again - failed

removed directory and initialized again

```
kweihe-mac:~ kweihe$ rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres/*
kweihe-mac:~ kweihe$ initdb  /usr/local/var/postgres
```

create role farm

```
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ psql
psql: FATAL:  database "kweihe" does not exist
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ createdb
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ psql
psql (9.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

kweihe=# create role farm with superuser;
CREATE ROLE
kweihe=# alter role farm with login;
ALTER ROLE
kweihe=# alter role farm with password '';
ALTER ROLE
```

started postgres server (generates postmaster.pid file)

```
kweihe-mac:~ kweihe$ postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

install pgcrypto extension

```
create extension if not exists pgcrypto schema pg_catalog;
```

create database

```
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ bundle exec rake db:create
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
kweihe-mac:pmpaware-webapp kweihe$ bundle exec rake db:seed
```